# Changing the background color dynamically using ".css()" method jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-plugins

I am currently working on calendar showing starting date and ending date of various projects in a hypothetical organisation, I have manage to do that using classes in javascript for each project

What I can't figure out is that :Is there to way to pass object values to .css() method in jQuery.

For example, can I do something like this :

```
$('this').css('background-color','object.colorCode');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the quotation for the second argument there. I guess `object` really is an object with the property `colorCode` which hopefully contains a useful value.

Currently you're passing in the string-value `"object.colorCode"` into the style, which obviously makes no sense at all.

Beyond that, `$('this')` on the other hand should have no quotation. `$(this)` please.

Comment: Yes it worked! ,this is my first stack overflow question and I look stupid now asking such question,anyway thanks for your help

Comment: @user1295276: you didn't look stupid at all. You asked the question in a clear and reasonable way (which is not so standard). Nothing wrong in asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass in `object.colorCode` without the quotes. Also `$(this)` shouldn't have quotes either so the statement should be:

```
$(this).css('background-color', object.colorCode);
```

That is assuming `colorCode` is a property of the `object`

Comment: yeah thanks,I've realized that ,I am new to stack overflow is there a way to show that a question is resolved?

Comment: click on check box outline you see left of the answer you accept